# Split data from one column into multiple columns and rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to make a dynamic calendar from a list of dates in the spreadsheet. The calendar would need to be spaced out with one column between each date, and two rows between each week. I also wanted to get this to work with leap years if possible. [Here's the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fm2adfkyA4EQS-OLA2uAn9zQbeIZ4tXlLsZ41bugNc4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 {TO_TEXT('Date List'!A1:A)&"♦ ♦"}, "select * limit 7", -1))), , 999)), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I shortened the formula a bit for it to be more readable:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TO_TEXT('Date List'!$A1:$A)&"♦ ♦"}, ,7)), "♦"))`